# Finding a constant in a particle motion problem using the energy equation

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

I have found V in terms of x, and then I have found the energy equation for x=1 and x=2. I've then set them equal to one another and solved, finding lambda = 20. I didn't use the values v=4 and v=2; since they are provided, I assume my method is incorrect/incomplete?

[image: Particle motion problem:]

Answer (score 2):

Only kinetic+potential energy is constant. You should not expect the kinetic energy to be constant. Instead, the change in the kinetic energy is $\int_1^2 F dx$, and it is also $\frac{1}{2} m \left ( v_2^2 - v_1^2 \right )$. Can you solve the resulting equation for $\lambda$?

Comment: Ok, I now have an equation 10 + (λ/2) = 40 + (λ/8). I am correct?

Comment: @Callum I'm not sure how you got two $\lambda$s. You should have $a \lambda = b$, where $a$ and $b$ are numbers (here $a \lambda = \int_1^2 F dx$ and $b=\frac{1}{2} m (v_2^2-v_1^2)$).

Comment: I got (3/8)λ=30. 

I have two equations for total mechanical energy, and have set them equal to one another.

Comment: @Callum Ah, I see, you just did the algebra in a slightly strange way. Yeah, that looks fine.

Comment: Thanks @Ian - i'm an amateur!

Answer (score 0):

Potential energy, alone, is not constant. It is the sum of potential and kinetic energy, which is a constant along the motion.